# Closing application using `activity. Finish()` causes malfunction on restart

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am using `activity. Finish()` to close an application on logout. However, when the application is opened back up again, my coroutines do not launch, more specifically, a `viewModelScope.launch` does not fire up. Could this because I am closing the application wrong? I would like to close the application and clear all viewModels and data from the application on logout

Here is how I am closing the application

```
val activity = (LocalContext.current as? Activity)
activity?. Finish()
```

Here is the coroutine that fails to launch on restart (user login)

```
fun login() {
    Log.d("Login test", "Attempt to login stage 1")
    viewModelScope.launch {
        Log.d("Collection test", "Attempt to login stage 2")
        userState = AuthResource.Loading
        try {
            
        } catch (e: IOException) {
           
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            
        } 
    }

}
```

The first log message is received, but never the second one and the loading state is never activated. I am using kotlin with jetpack compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an Activity finishes, the associated view model is terminated.  Coroutines that haven't run yet won't be run.  That's part of the point of a viewModel-  it's bound to a lifecycle, and that lifecycle ends with the Activity.  You need to run it on another scope if you want to ensure it happens.

Comment: I moved my requests to a custom scope to ensure that they are always called and it worked as per the suggestion by Gabe